# Unable to startActivity in android

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Android developing.
I'm trying to start another activity from **MainActivity** but it forces close.

> Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
> SecondActivity.class);
> startActivity(myIntent);

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More details of your code and error message needed but I think you've forgotten to add SecondActivity to AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="SecondActivity"/>
```